# Infopath Href problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html

i have created a link in my main page in Sharepoint 2007, I'm trying to create a link reference to open the form that i publush in my form library. But the problem is that whenever i click the link, it direct me to the library form page instead of opening the form. Anyone can help me out?

```
 href="http://myServer/test/InfoPath/Forms/ALLItems.aspx?XsnLocation=http://myserver/test/infopath/form.xsn"
```

Comment: maybe add "?OpenInBrowser=true" at the end ? or something similar

Comment: In the library where you have published the form, can you access it using the New menu item? That way you can get the url of the form.

Comment: @Manu No, whenever i click new document it ask me to search the xml. it's that the reason?

Comment: @Nico I've tried that too, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HyperLink as follows

```
<a href="http://myserver/test/infopath/form.xsn">Publish Form</a>
```

Give this a try

```
<a href="http://myserver/test/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=~sitecollection/infopath/template.xsn&SaveLocation=~sitecollection/infopath&Source=~sitecollection/infopath">Publish Form</a>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms772417.aspx

I tried this exactly like the href that you gave me , but it still redirect me to the form library and not open it

```
href="http://myServer/testpage/infoPath/Forms/AllItems.aspx?XsnLocation=http://myServer/testpage/infopath/form.xsn&SaveLocation=http://myServer/testpage/infopath&Source=http://myServer/testpage/infopath"
```

Comment: I did that and it force me to save the form in my library but what i want is to open in the browser.

Comment: Is your form browser enabled?  Is it published as a content type?

Comment: no, but it does open when i am in the library form, it didn't ask me to save the form.

Comment: if the form isn't browser enabled then Amal's solution should open it in client, provided you have InfoPath client or filler installed

Comment: @user3281912 check the update. I just typed the URL, so you might need to adjust based on your setup.

Comment: It still direct me only to the form library